# How to create a common search bar in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am working on an application in which i want to create a search bar which will be able to search for individual users as well as brands.

For this i have written a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM temp_users,brand_pages WHERE firstname LIKE'%$find%' or lastname LIKE '%$find%' or name LIKE '%$find%'
```

I checked the query but it is not as needed. What is the way it can be done ??

Should i use joins ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need join.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp_users AS TU
INNER JOIN brand_pages AS BP
WHERE (TU.firstname LIKE "%$find%" OR TU.lastname LIKE "%$find%" OR BP.name LIKE "%$find%")
```

Edit: If you are using this query in PHP and trying to use the variable `$find` inline, use double quotes (not single quotes).